# Create a video slideshow from images using ffmpeg programmatically

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

Is there any way to create a video slideshow from images using ffmpeg without using the exe?? ie, I have to do this with the dll and lib they give.

Please give me suggestions.

Comment: [Get the current ffmpeg source code](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#GettingFFmpeg) and refer to the various API usage examples in `docs/examples`.

Comment: Can we create a Solution file for ffmpeg in vs2010?